# Calling super methods inside separate scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to call a `super` method from inside a different scope, but this doesn't appear to be working.

```
'use strict';

class One {
    test() {
        console.log('test');
    }
 }

class Two extends One {
    hi() {
        super.test();
    }
    hello() {
        var msg = 'test';
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             console.log(msg);
             super.test();
        });
    }
}

var two = new Two();
two.hi();
two.hello();
```

Comment: You didn't set the preprocessor on CodePen, so it's trying to use ES6 features which may be missing in your browser. Set the JavaScript preprocessor to Babel

Comment: @RGraham While that works in CodePen, I'm running this in a Node application. (v4.0.0)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about the demo, I see the tag now. Perhaps Babel can't transpile this and NodeJS exhibiting correct behavior. Good Question - I would just remove your demo :)

Comment: @RGraham I'm not sure why the other answer was removed, but using arrow functions actually solved the problem. `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { super.test(); })`

Comment: I think they panicked because of my incorrect comment. But the answer is correct. *Why* that works though when Babel doesn't see it that way is the question.

Comment: I deleted it because it was only semi-correct. Changing the preprocessor indeed solved it in codepen. Do you have any source on the scope of `super` in ES6? I can't really find anything with a definite answer.

Comment: @ralh [Found it](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/specifics-of-class-and-super) (down atm, Google for cached version) Babel is wrong, Node's implementation (and your answer) is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, in Babel it works right out of the box. In node though, it appears that in that anonymous function, `this` is no longer bound to the `two` object and `super` is not available then. You can use a fat arrow to bind `this` to the scope of the anonymous function:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Message: ', msg);
    super.test();
});
```

If you're not familiar with the concept of fat arrows and/or `this` scope, this is a good read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions