# Calling super() method inside Promise: 'super' keyword unexpected here?

Tags: inheritance, scope, ecmascript-6, super, es6-promise

I'm trying to call super method `save()` from child instance.

```
// ImageKeeper.js
'use strict';

module.exports = class ImageKeeper extends FileKeeper {
  constructor(keeperPath, options) {
    super(`/${keeperPath}`, options)
    this.keeperPath = keeperPath;
  }

  save(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this
        .resolvePath(filePath)
        .then(function(fileData) {
          var filePath = fileData[0],
            mime = fileData[1];

          super.save(filePath, mime); // <-- GETTING ERROR HERE
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          reject(err)
        })
    })
  }
}

// FileKeeper.js
'use strict';

module.exports = class FileKeeper {
  constructor(keeperPath, options) {
    this.storagePath = path.resolve(`${env.paths.storage}${keeperPath}`);
    this.options = options;
  }

  save(filePath, mime) {
    return Promise
      ...
  }
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
/src/filekeeper/imagekeeper.js:110
          super.save(filePath, mime);
          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
```

If I move `super.save(filePath, mime);` in the beginning of `save()` method, it works.

**I've tried bind context to upper scope:**

```
save(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this
      .then((fileData) => { // <-- bind context to upper scope

        super.save(filePath, mime);
```

But I'm getting:

```
Unhandled rejection SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:374:17)
From previous event:
    at /src/filekeeper/imagekeeper.js:106:10
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710546/calling-super-methods-inside-separate-scope), but no luck.

Any ideas? Thank you.

#### env

```
root@8d1024b233c3:/src# node -v
  v4.1.1

docker -v
  Docker version 1.8.2, build 0a8c2e3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you've found a bug in V8's handling of `super`; I've reported the bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4466) and they've triaged it as `Type-Bug` and `Priority-Medium`. This is after looking into it in some detail, resulting in my posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943776/using-super-within-an-arrow-function-within-an-arrow-function-within-a-method), where [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32944304/157247) confirmed my suspicion it was a V8 bug.

Provided you use arrow functions (not `function` functions) as per your "I've tried bind context to upper scope" comment (the main code block is using a `function` function, which won't work), it *should* be working.

While waiting for a fix, it works if you put that logic in a method:

```
someAppropriateName(fileData) {
  var filePath = fileData[0],
    mime = fileData[1];

  super.save(filePath, mime);
}
```

...and call that method from the promise callback:

```
save(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this
      .resolvePath(filePath)
      .then(fileData => {                      // **
          this.someAppropriateName(fileData);  // **
      })                                       // **
      .catch(function(err) {
        reject(err)
      })
  })
}
```

or:

```
save(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this
      .resolvePath(filePath)
      .then(this.someAppropriateName.bind(this)) // **
      .catch(function(err) {
        reject(err)
      })
  })
}
```

That works because the bug is fairly obscure: It only crops up if you have an arrow function inside *another* arrow function inside a method, and the innermost arrow function uses a variable or argument defined by the outer arrow function (using stuff from the method itself is fine).

---

Some other notes, though:

1. If `FileKeeper`'s `save` returns a promise, it seems like `ImageKeeper` should be using that and chaining off it. Your code just throws away the result of calling `super.save(...)`.
2. When you find yourself writing `new Promise`, always stop and ask yourself if the code in question is *really* the root of the chain. Very, very, very often it isn't (and I suspect it isn't in your code). Remember that every `then` returns a promise, and the power of promises lies primarily in the chain. Don't break the chain if you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you for deep investigation. Right now I've ended with moving inner function into separate one and applying context with `this._save.bind(this)`. Also, removed extra Promise constructors, thank you and @Benjamin for taking time to point me out this flaw :).

Comment: @f1nn: No worries. It was very interesting, and answering the question proved to me that my understanding of `super` was, um, superficial. :-) Learned a lot in the process of fixing that.